# How to enable deletion and edition of a specific entity in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I can't figure out how to set up my custom entity in order to be able to delete and edit it. Please, any advice! Thanks in advance.[image]

As in the screenshots, the current user can't delete or edit entity `Fractie`. So, My goal is to allow this user to be able to perform deletion and edits on this specific object.

Please, any tips?

I am using `sonata.admin.security.handler.acl: ACL and ROLES` to handle permissions

Comment: As in the screenshots, the current user can't delete or edit entity Fractie. So, My goal is to allow this user to be able to perform deletion and edition on this specific object. Please, any tip? I am using "sonata.admin.security.handler.acl: ACL and ROLES to handle permissions"

Comment: as I remember is quite simple ROLE naming. smth like ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ENTITY_NAME_DELETE or ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_ENTITY_NAME_EDIT, check it out here - https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html. so your user should have such a roles

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question. This is better than adding extra content as a comment.

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question. This is better than adding extra content as a comment.

Comment: Martin Evans, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After a closer look to the docs [Sonata Security](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html), I solved this problem following these steps:

```
1. Run: php bin/console sonata:admin:generate-object-acl --step
2. After running this command you'll see this message: Generate ACLs for the object instances handled by "sonata.admin.theNameOfYourObject"
3. Type yes or no for any object/entity that you need ACLs to be generated for
4. That is it! Good luck!
```